How do I remove the "Ask Copilot" button from Microsoft Edge?
When I open a PDF file with Microsoft Edge in Windows 11, there is an "Ask Copilot" button in the top left corner. How do I remove the Ask Copilot button from Edge?


Do you get this prompt when you're just browsing the internet on Edge, or is it only when you're opening PDFs? Is this a business-owned computer, or a personal computer?

I do not get the prompt when browsing the internet, only when opening PDFs. Using a personal computer.

Are you using Edge's PDF renderer, or do you have Adobe Reader handling rendering duties in Edge? I'm guessing it's Edge handling the rendering, but can you please check your Reader and Browser settings to confirm?

In Edge, go to Settings > Appearance > Copilot, and disable "Show Copilot".

I do not see "Copilot" as an option under Appearance.

@Stevoisiak] edge://settings/sidebar/appSettings?hubApp=cd4688a9-e888-48ea-ad81-76193d56b1be searching Settings is helpful.

I guess this is moving a lot around but as an update to @music2myear (as of Nov 2024) and a step further to @Ramhound, this is now in
Sidebar>App and notification settings>Copilot

